# Get the detected objects as an index in to a database - opencv classifier training

Tags: opencv

Is there any method to get the count of detected objects in trained classifier with opencv.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method detectMultiscale will fill your vector of rectangles (namely objects):

```
vector<Rect> FaceRects;
CascadeFace.detectMultiScale(   MatImg,
                                FaceRects,
                                1.1,
                                1,
                                0,
                                Size(24, 24) );

FaceRects.size() // <-- count of detected objects
```

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale

Comment: This is not what you looking for?

Comment: Thank you Riccardo